# How to compare data in ViewBags in a loop?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, input, viewbag

I'm trying to compare datas from two different ViewBags which contain each of them a list of objects and if two objects are the same I would like to display a checkbox checked and if not, a checkbox not checked. I've tried that:

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Fonctions.Count(); i++)
        {
               for (int y = 0; y < ViewBag.FonctionsContact.Count(); y++)
                   {
                       if (ViewBag.Fonctions[i] == ViewBag.FonctionsContact[y])
                       {
                           <input type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.Fonctions[i].IdFonction" checked/>
                        }
                         else
                         {
                           <input type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.Fonctions[i].IdFonction"/>
                         }
                    }
        }
```

But it shows me an error RuntimeBindingException. Maybe there are different ways to do that... Somebody has an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call extension methods (`.Count()` in your case) on dynamic variables. This is a limitation of .NET that has nothing to do with ASP.NET MVC.

So you will have to use the corresponding property. For example if those are arrays use `.Length` and if they are collections use `.Count`

```
@for (int i = 0; i < ViewBag.Fonctions.Count; i++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < ViewBag.FonctionsContact.Count; y++)
    {
        if (ViewBag.Fonctions[i] == ViewBag.FonctionsContact[y])
        {
            <input type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.Fonctions[i].IdFonction" checked/>
        }
        else
        {
            <input type="checkbox" value="@ViewBag.Fonctions[i].IdFonction"/>
        }
    }
}
```

Of course this is just some hacky stuff, the correct solution to this problem is obviously to get rid of ViewBag and use strongly typed view model where you wouldn't have had such problems at all.

Comment: Thank you but the thing is that i'm using data from two models so I can't use strongly typed Views...

Comment: Of course that you can. That's exactly the purpose of a view model. So basically you're gonna have a view model that is aggregating the other models and your view will become strongly typed to the view model. Everytime you use ViewBag, you are doing ASP.NET MVC the wrong way.